Deprecation Warning in Vue 3 with Sass: Styles Not Applying Correctly
I'm working on a Vue 3 project and recently encountered the following deprecation warning in the terminal:
Deprecation Warning: Sass's behavior for declarations that appear after nested rules will be changing to match the behavior specified by CSS in an upcoming   version. To keep the existing behavior, move the declaration above the nested  rule. To opt into the new behavior, wrap the declaration in & {}.`
Since this warning appeared, all my styles seem to be off, and I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. I'm using Sass for styling, and the problem started after I made some updates.

On line 37 is

Here are a few details:

Vue version: ^3.2.37
Sass version: ^1.54.5

What I've tried:

Delete the node_module folder and reinstall all the dependencies

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Vue3 and Bootstrap do not do well.

Try this:
npm i sass@1.77.6 --save-exact

And if it not worked mention your bootstrap version too.

There is a breaking change note at sass. See here
Here you can have a look at the ticket for the boostrap problem.
Cant help you anymore as this is not resolved yet.
